# MS Excel VBA to find range formatted with "Center across Selection" horizontal alignment

Tags: excel, text-alignment, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the text "Hello, this is a long line of text" in cell A1.  I have selected cells A1:G1.

I know if I use the line `Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection` in a macro, it will format the selected cells using the horizontal text alignment option "Center across Selection".

How can I write a function that will do the inverse operation, i.e. given cell A1, return the range A1:G1 ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what are the criteria for returning A1:G1 given A1 ?  A contiguous block of cells with "center" formatting?  No gaps and only one column wide?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
Public Function CAS(r As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range
    CAS = ""

    If r.HorizontalAlignment H<> 7 Then Exit Function
    Set rng = r

    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        If r.Offset(0, i).HorizontalAlignment <> 7 Then
            CAS = rng.Address(0, 0)
            Exit Function
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, r.Offset(0, i))
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

This assumes that ***7*** is the correct enuneration for `HorizontalAlignment`